# glyphicon arrow up is not working when used offline css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using arrow up glyph-icon using Bootstrap. when i applied downloaded css in HTML it is not working, but if used full HTTP css path in online it works.below is my code, tell me where is wrong in my code,is it browser version is dependent? if I used https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css. this complete path it works.but I need to add offline.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="w3-container">
  <button class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-circle w3-red w3-card-4"> <span class="glyphicon">&#xe093;</span></button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your current bootstrap link will only work if it's in the top level directory with your html file. If it's in a directory, you need to state that in the Link call.

Comment: There you go:  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>

Comment: I tried this  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span> but it is not working. I downloaded bootstrap.min.css file and put in directory and called that file in html. but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this 
`<span class="glyphicon">&#xe093;</span>`

with

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>`

**More information :** 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/

Comment: While this is absolutely true (and it works for me with glyphicon-arrow-down, -left and -right) I can only agree with @vishwa that the up-arrow is somewhat bugged and simply just doesn't show up. I'm also using 3.3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Well, at least if you use the µBlock plug-in in your browser.

For me it worked when checking the "Ignore generic cosmetic filter"-option (or whatever it is called in English) on the "Prepared Filters"-page (or whatever it is called in English).

I tried to figure out where the source of this feature is located to see how that cosmetic filter works, but couldn't find it. I mean there might be a way to work around that cosmetic filter if the element with the glyphicon would be coded differently.